# How to tackle this puzzle?

Tags: java, c++, c, math, puzzle

Disclaimer: This is not a homework problem. I stumbled upon this puzzle [here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/36552/how-to-tackle-this-puzzle-closed) and I also have the answer. However, I am not able to figure out an approach to arrive at the solution.

The puzzle is as given below:

The product of the ages of David's children is the square of the sum of their ages. David has less than eight children. None of his children have the same age. None of his children is more than 14 years old. All of his children is at least two years old. How many children does David have, and what are their ages?

The answer happens to be 2,4,6,12.

Please suggest a way to solve this problem programmatically.

Comment: SO is specifically dedicated for programming questions.. You have already gotten the logic in the above link. `1.` What programming languages are you planning to approach the question with? `2.` Do you have programming experience?

Comment: @bonCodigo Yeah, I do have 2 years of programming experience. Proficient in C,C++ and Java. I tried with C++, but seems to be a bit lengthy. So, I'm going with Java. But still couldn't get the spark/idea to start with.

Comment: Then you are better off showing the code (possibly the main logic snippet) you have tried and retag your question with correct programming language and indicate where you are stuck...or where you need efficiency.. It will also notify subject experts to your question :)

Comment: My first approach is pretty fatuous. If I add the code, it will definitely confuse the reader. I'm just thinking of a new approach. And thanks for your advice, I'll retag my question to java.

Comment: Welcome to SO! I suggest that you start by describing, in English, the steps you might take to reach a solution. Then try to translate those steps into code. When you have specific questions along the way, please come ask them here.

Comment: @FrodoBaggins This is an interesting question.. you could easily solve it using a Recursive method..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it in java using a recursive approach. 
First the program prints all the combinations, then gives the correct combination (that matches the specified criteria) at last.

This program instantly gives the output

```
(2, 4, 6, 12)
```

just as you have specified in your question.

```
public class Tackle {
static int[] ages = {2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14};   // Since the program uses a recursive function,
static StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer("");          // the variables are declared as static
static int x=0,occurances=0;
static int sum,pdt=1,count=0;
static String[] instances = new String[100];
static void recurse(int a[], int k, int n) throws Exception
{
    if(k==n)    // This program obtains various combinations using binary technique
    {
        for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
            if(a[i] == 1){
                    System.out.print(ages[i]+" ");   // Displays all the combinations available             
                    sum = sum + ages[i];
                    pdt = pdt * ages[i];  
                    count++;                                        
                    sb.append(String.valueOf(ages[i]+" "));
                    }
                    if(Math.pow(sum, 2) == pdt && count<8){     // Checking the criteria
                        instances[occurances++] = sb.toString();
                    }

                    sb = new StringBuffer("");
                    count = 0;
                    sum = 0;
                    pdt = 1;
                    System.out.println("");
    }
    else for(int i=0;i<=1;i++)
    {       
        a[x++] = i;
        recurse(a,k+1,n);
        x--;
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    int[] a = new int[10000];
    recurse(a,0,ages.length);
    if(occurances>0)
    {
        System.out.println("No of combinations matching: " + occurances);
        for(int i=0;i<occurances;i++)
        System.out.println("The combination of ages is [ " + instances[i] + "]");
    }
    else
        System.out.println("No combination matches the criteria. ");
}
}
```

The output obtained was

```
[All possible combinations are listed here]
No of combinations matching: 1
The combination of ages is [ 2 4 6 12 ]
```

Comment: Nice, a code in java is what I was looking for. By the way, this being a really challenging problem, what was the approach you used to solve it?

Answer (score 5):

In Python (Which is not what you asked, but you're more asking for an algorithm):

```
import operator
import itertools

possible_ages = range(2,15)

# If the list of ages passed to this function returns true, then this solves the puzzle.
def valid(ages):
    product_of_ages = reduce(operator.mul, ages, 1)
    square_of_sum_of_ages = reduce(operator.add, ages, 0) ** 2
    return product_of_ages == square_of_sum_of_ages

for number_of_children in range(1, 9):
    for ages in itertools.combinations(possible_ages, number_of_children):
        if valid(ages):
            print ages
```

And that prints, almost immediately:

```
(2, 4, 6, 12)
```

Comment: Wow! I'm truly amazed at your code. Is python always that cool? can we use the itertools.combinations() type of functions in ACM ICPC or CodeChef or other programming contests like that? aren't the built-in functions restricted in the programming contests?

Comment: Also, you've checked only for range(1, 9).. what about the rest of the ages? Are they included implicitly?

Comment: @FrodoBaggins: When I did the ACM ICPC, Python was not a valid language. That may have changed in the last few years. I'm not sure.

Comment: @FrodoBaggins: `possible_ages` is the tuple containing the set of possible ages for each child. This is the set of numbers `[2, 14]` inclusive. `range(2, 15)` does not include the last number (that's how the function works). So I am doing children from age 2 to 14. The `range(1,9)`, is to look for a valid set of size 1, then 2, then 3, and on until 8.

Comment: @FrodoBaggins: Yeah. I rechecked actually. The languages are still Java, C and C++.

Answer (score 1):

You don't specify that the ages are all integers, but I'm going to assume that's true.  If so, there are only about 1e9 possible combinations of those ages among 8 children.  Simply enumerate (`for(age1=2; age1<15; age1++) { for(age2=2; age2<15; age2++) { ...`) them all and test.  Your computer should finish that task within a few minutes even in a script interpreter.

There are optimizations to be applied, because hard-coding "8" loops is clumsy, and because the age lists are order-independent (having children of "4 and 2" is the same thing as "2 and 4"), but frankly I don't think that's worth it here.  Your time taken coding the extra steps will take more time than you'll save at runtime.

Comment: An easy optimization: `for(age2=age1+1; ...)` etcetera.

Comment: Hey Andy, what do you mean by 1e9 possible combinations? Does that indicate a specific function?